# Oracle: почему не видит значение во вложенном select

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT pev.id AS SPEV_ID,
       npev.id     AS id,
       npev.isnormal,
       npev.islongterm,
       npev.ispv,
       npev.isfreezed,
       npev.PESTATUS_ID
FROM   tplanelemversion pev
INNER  JOIN tclosure cl
ON     cl.id = pev.id
LEFT   OUTER JOIN tclosure ncl
ON     ncl.root_id = cl.root_id 
AND    ncl.id > cl.id
LEFT   OUTER JOIN tplanelemversion npev
ON     npev.id = ncl.id 
where  npev.id = 
       (select min(cl1.id) 
        from   tclosure cl1, 
               (select * from tplanelemversion where isPV = 1) pev1
        where  cl1.root_id = cl.root_id 
        and    pev1.id = cl1.id 
        and    pev1.id > pev.id)    
or     npev.id = 
       (select min(cl1.id) 
          from   tclosure cl1, 
                 (select * from tplanelemversion where isNormal = 1) pev1
          where  cl1.root_id = cl.root_id 
          and    pev1.id = cl1.id 
          and    pev1.id > pev.id)
or     npev.id = 
       (select min(cl1.id) 
        from   tclosure cl1, 
               (select * from tplanelemversion where isLongterm = 1) pev1
        where  cl1.root_id = cl.root_id 
        and    pev1.id = cl1.id 
        and    pev1.id > pev.id);
```

Пытаюсь оптимизировать запрос, потому что в таблицах tclosure и tplanelemversion очень много значений (в outer-объединении - около 80ккк записей), так что работает непростительно долго.
Попытка упростить одно из условий до следующего:

```
npev.id = (
    select min(cl1.id) 
    from  (
          select * 
          from   tclosure 
          where  root_id = cl.root_id) cl1, 
          (
                 select * 
                 from   tplanelemversion 
                 where   isPV = 1 
                 and     id > pev.id
           ) pev1
    where  pev1.id = cl1.id)
```

успехом не увенчалась: `ORA-00904`, он не знает, что такое cl и pev (пробовал оба изменения по отдельности). 
Прошу объяснить, почему он перестаёт их видеть и как это исправить. Спасибо.

Comment: Странно у вас выглядит "упростить", мне кажется так проще: `or npev.id = (select min(cl1.id) from tclosure cl1, tplanelemversion pev1 where cl1.root_id = cl.root_id and pev1.id = cl1.id and pev1.id > pev.id and pev1.isLongterm = 1)`  И я почти уверен, что от OR в основном запросе вообще можно избавится.

Comment: 1) от or такой вариант не избавит, потому что нужно чтобы либо, isPV = 1, либо isNormal = 1, либо isLongterm = 1, но не все три вместе.

2) если согнать все три условия в одно, после outer-объединения с tclosure получатся те самые 80ккк строк, которые запрашиваются очень долго

Comment: Т.е. вам надо  `(isPV+isNormal+isLongterm)=1 and 1 in(isPV,isNormal,isLongterm)` ?

Comment: правда последнее мой сказанное явно никак не индексируется

Comment: И такой вариант как я привел как минимум избавляет от ненужных уровней вложенности и избаляет от проблемы недоступности каких то имен

Comment: И если вы говорите что объединение условий в одно приведет к тем самым 80ккк то значит сейчас каждый из этих 3х подзапросов все равно получает 1/3 от этого кол-ва и никак не защищает от _"но не все три вместе"_, потому что те записи в которых присутствуют два признака будут сейчас отобраны в два подзапроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению в Oracle нельзя обращаться к таблице, объявленной в запросе на 2 уровня вложенности выше. Кроме того абсолютно не понятно, зачем вы делаете такую вложенность, да еще внутри подзапросов делаете `select *` вместо выборки только нужных столбцов. Вполне могут быть ситуации, что оракл некоторые колонки берет прямо по индексу по которому ищет и при этом не обращаться к данным. А ваш `select *` на корню отключает такое его поведение, потому как оптимизатор начинает считать, что обязательно надо выбрать всю запись. Это само по себе может приводить к серьезному снижению производительности запросов. И еще обращение к одной и той же таблице `tclosure` в 3х OR основного запроса явно не идет на пользу производительности.

Предлагаю переписать запрос примерно так:

```
SELECT pev.id AS SPEV_ID,
       npev.id     AS id,
       npev.isnormal,
       npev.islongterm,
       npev.ispv,
       npev.isfreezed,
       npev.PESTATUS_ID
  FROM tplanelemversion pev
  INNER JOIN tclosure cl
    ON cl.id = pev.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tclosure ncl
    ON ncl.root_id = cl.root_id AND ncl.id     > cl.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tplanelemversion npev
    ON npev.id = ncl.id 
  where npev.id in
      (
       select min(cl1.id)
         from tclosure cl1, tplanelemversion pev1,
              (select 1 as num from DUAL union select 2 from DUAL union select 3 from DUAL)
        where cl1.root_id = cl.root_id and pev1.id = cl1.id
          and cl1.id > pev.id
          and (   (num=1 and pev1.isLongterm = 1)
               or (num=2 and pev1.isNormal = 1)
               or (num=3 and pev1.isPV = 1)
              )
        group by num
      )
```

И конечно надо внимательно смотреть план выполнения. Периодически лучшие по виду конструкции приводят к совершенно не оптимальным планам выполнения.

Обратите внимание, я в подзапросе заменил `pev1.id > pev.id` на равнозначный `cl1.id > pev.id` (т.к. есть условие `pev1.id = cl1.id`) - это может улучшить скорость выполнения, потому как оптимизатор однозначно видит, что надо приклеить tclosure по root_id и отфильтровать только записи с `id>` и после этого только приступать к `tplanelemversion`. В противном случае, ему вполне могло придти в голову отобрать сначала *все* записи `tplanelemversion` с `id>pev.id` и только потом полезть с tclosure.

И я совершенно не понял, зачем вам в основном запросе таблица `pev`. Вы из нее берете только id, причем равную `id` из `tclosure`. Так что, если у вас больше нет каких то улословий не указанных в вопросе, то она совершенно не нужна.

Comment: Благодарю, применил некоторые из ваших советов, стало быстрее.

Comment: @maxMrScapegracerubanov Вообще сам подзапрос, который отдает список id вышестоящему и при этом сам зависит от него может сильно тормозить. Я вчера, когда проверял работоспособность идеи на единственной табличке с 4к записей столкнулся с тем, что он начинал безбожно тормозить при таком подходе. Возможно было бы лучше сформировать одним подзапросом список всех id которые потребуются наверху и скопом туда отдать, ну т.е. вынести `cl` в сам подзапрос и вернуть `cl.id,min(cl1.id) group by cl.id, num` и уже к этим id left доклеить остальное. Не видя данных, конечно, сказать применимо ли это нельзя